# Using `calc()` vs `transform` when placing elements

Tags: css, css-transforms

Is there a reason one would want to use `calc()` over the `transform` property when placing an element, or vise versa, when the size of the element is known?

For example...

```
.element {
  bottom: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-9px);
}
```

Produces the same results as:

```
.element {
  bottom: calc(100% + 9px);
}
```

If the size of the element is *not* known, I see the advantage of using `transform`. However, if the size is known (as above) I can just as easily use `calc()` to adjust.

**"`calc()` uses just one line, while `transform` requires two lines"**

Fair enough. But (in my case) I'm already using `transform` to adjust along the other axis (because I *don't* know the initial size), so I could easily combine the `translateY()` and `translateX()` to actually *reduce* the number of lines.

**"Because browser support"**

Assume we have full browser support across both solutions.

Is there a standard, or performance situation, that would suggest one solution is better than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transform` is a monster capable of doing much more powerful things than simple translations.

Therefore, it has some collateral effects like establishing a containing block for its descendants, even if they are in a fixed position!

Therefore, as a rule of thumb, when you only want simple translations, I would recommend to avoid `transform`. I prefer `calc()`, margins, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Transforms can be affected by *other* transforms, which may cause a difference in rendering. For example, if you were using the `perspective` transform, `translateY()` would take place inside that perspective. So, the perspective would be applied, and then the element would be transformed according to the vanishing point you set.

If you were using `calc()`, instead, the element would be positioned on the page irrespective of the set perspective. It’s probably a subtle difference, but it’s there.

If you’re not using a 3D transform like `perspective`, however, or if `translate()` is the only transform you’re using, I don’t think there’s a difference.